# Module.js: 471 throw err in Mac

Tags: reactjs

When I tried to run my React app. This problem pops up. It all started when I updated node for another project. That was compatible with this one. I have must done something wrong when trying to change node version.
I tried to uninstall and re-install npm, but the error keeps poping up.
The error have been changing while I tried different things. I am quite lost at this point.

```
> npm start
> module.js:471
> throw err;
>     ^
> 
> Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
> at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/guadalupeabrile/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
> at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "scoda",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "d3-ease": "^2.0.0",
    "dom-helpers": "^5.2.1",
    "fslightbox-react": "^1.4.9",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "gsap": "^3.6.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.2.6",
    "lax.js": "^1.2.5",
    "rc-collapse": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-autosize-textarea": "^7.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-countdown": "^2.2.1",
    "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icofont": "^1.0.19",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-id-swiper": "^4.0.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-masonry-css": "^1.0.16",
    "react-move": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.4.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-tabs": "^3.1.0",
    "react-text-loop": "^2.3.0",
    "react-text-rotator": "^1.1.0",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "shufflejs": "^5.2.3",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "swiper": "^6.6.1",
    "use-lax": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `are-we-there-yet` present in your project package.json dependencies?

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: The error changed while i tried to uninstall and etc. I am quite lost at this point.

Comment: You should check your package.json file to be sure. If it's not present, then you should install it: `npm i -D are-we-there-yet`.

Comment: Also, why are you using Node.js 6? It is very old and unmaintained.

Comment: I just updated the post with the package.json.

Comment: You can see that it is missing so you need to add it as I recommended in one of my previous comments.

Comment: Updated node. And now this error appears.

Comment: >> nvm use --lts
Now using node v18.14.0 (npm v9.3.1)
>> node -v
v18.14.0
>> npm start

> scoda@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found

Comment: Tried the command that you recommend.  i -D are-we-there-yet
bash: i: command not found

Comment: `npm install -D are-we-there-yet`